# Run action failure

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So in my game I want a simple frame by frame animation. The animation works fine when I use it in the init function, however once I stop the action and attempt to restart it nothing happens.

this is in the init

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
         @"Dubstep Dan_default.plist"];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode
                                          batchNodeWithFile:@"Dubstep Dan_default.png"];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];

        walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1-%d.png", i]]];
        }
        walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

        self.character = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"1-1.png"];
        _character.position = ccp(80, 260);
        self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                           [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
       // self.walkAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim];
        [_character runAction:_walkAction];
        [_walkAction retain]; 
        [spriteSheet addChild:_character];
```

and this is in my game tick function

```
if(gp.isControlling && (gp.controlQuadrant == 0 || gp.controlQuadrant == 1) && (_character.position.x < 250))
    {

        if([_walkAction isDone]) {
            [_character runAction:_walkAction];
            NSLog(@"TEST"); 
        }
        targetX = 7;
        _character.scale = 1;
    }
else {
        [_character stopAction:_walkAction];
        targetX = 0;
```

Comment: did you breakpoint and debug this, see if you even enter the 'if (gp. ...' clause ?

Comment: It does because when i use the joystick the character moves right

Comment: should i repeat my question ?

Comment: I guess im not sure what you mean

Comment: place a breakpoint inside the if([_walkAction isDone]) when true and and when false clauses. Run your game and check that you get there when you expect to. If you do, something is broken with the action, or the run action. If not, something is broken with the logic.

Comment: So i added the breakpoints as you suggested as well as an else statement for the walkAction isDone and the program never enters the if statement and defaults to the else. Does this mean the logic is flawed?

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d actions are not reentrant (reusable). Run once and forget. Need to run again? Create a new action.

There have been attempts at working around this, but I would generally advise against it because depending on the action being reused reusing actions by calling their init method again can leak memory. Plus it's just bad style to call init again on an object.

Comment: I have reused animation actions with no problems before (and still do). However, the logic surrounding their use precludes reusing while in use, similar to what is attempted here i think.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem with a simple boolean value

```
 if(!_moving) {
            [_character runAction:_walkAction];
            _moving = TRUE;
        }
```